# Error with training logistic regression model on Apache Spark. SPARK-5063

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I am trying to build a Logistic Regression model with Apache Spark.
Here is the code.

```py
parsedData = raw_data.map(mapper) # mapper is a function that generates pair of label and feature vector as LabeledPoint object
featureVectors = parsedData.map(lambda point: point.features) # get feature vectors from parsed data 
scaler = StandardScaler(True, True).fit(featureVectors) #this creates a standardization model to scale the features
scaledData = parsedData.map(lambda lp: LabeledPoint(lp.label, scaler.transform(lp.features))) #trasform the features to scale mean to zero and unit std deviation
modelScaledSGD = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(scaledData, iterations = 10)
```

But I get this error:

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

I am not sure how to work around this. Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem you see is pretty much the same as the one I've described in [How to use Java/Scala function from an action or a transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684842/1560062) To transform you have to call Scala function, and it requires access to the `SparkContext` hence the error you see.

Standard way to handle this is to process only the required part of your data and then zip the results.

```
labels = parsedData.map(lambda point: point.label)
featuresTransformed = scaler.transform(featureVectors)

scaledData = (labels
    .zip(featuresTransformed)
    .map(lambda p: LabeledPoint(p[0], p[1])))

modelScaledSGD = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(...)
```

If don't plan to implement your own methods based on `MLlib` components it could easier to use high level [`ML` API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline).

**Edit**:

There are two possible problems here.

1. At this point `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` supports [only binomial](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10179) classification (Thanks to [eliasah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah) for pointing that out) . If you need multi-label classification you can replace it with `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`.
2. `StandardScaler` supports only dense vectors so it has limited applications.

Comment: it gives this [error](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/cc6287b4307123e5755a). I've never seen this error before.

Comment: Works fine on 1.4.1. I'll download 1.3.1 later and check if I can reproduce the problem. `StandardScaler` won't work on sparse data but I doesn't look like it is the problem here.

Comment: The solution sounds logical and correct to me and that's why I was surprised by the error.

Comment: I think I know what is going on. You're using millionsong data but `LogisticRegressionWithSGD` is expecting binary classification problem. Could you checks logs for [this message](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/DataValidators.scala#L40)?

Comment: Spark seems to be complaining about the input but that seems to be it.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-classification-regression.html) LogisticRegression* supports Multiclass Classification. Is there a JIRA ticket concerning this or I have skipped something.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is only place in GLM code where `Input validation failed` can be generated and it is from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f5b028ed2f1ad6de43c8b50ebf480e1b6c047035/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala#L247). LR is using [`binaryLabelValidator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f5b028ed2f1ad6de43c8b50ebf480e1b6c047035/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/LogisticRegression.scala#L224)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87888/discussion-between-eliasah-and-zero323).

Comment: Thank you @zero323 for the answer. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @eliasah I used validateData=False option with LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train method and I don't get 'Input validation error' anymore. I hope it helps you too.

Comment: @ashishsjsu There no need for that. `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS` has [numClasses](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/45281664e0d3b22cd63660ca8ad6dd574f10e21f/python/pyspark/mllib/classification.py#L323) argument.

Comment: I did use numClasses argument, but I was still getting the error.