# How to prepare for training data in mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

**TL;DR;**
How do I use `mllib` to train my wiki data (text & category) for prediction against tweets?

I have trouble figuring out how to convert my tokenized wiki data so that it can be trained through either `NaiveBayes` or `LogisticRegression`. My goal is to use the trained model for comparison against tweets*. I've tried using pipelines with LR and `HashingTF` with `IDF` for `NaiveBayes` but I keep getting wrong predictions. Here's what I've tried:

*Note that I would like to use the many categories in the wiki data for my labels...I've only seen binary classification (it's one category or another)....is it possible to do what I want?

### Pipeline w LR

```scala
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer

case class WikiData(category: String, text: String)
case class LabeledData(category: String, text: String, label: Double)

val wikiData = sc.parallelize(List(WikiData("Spark", "this is about spark"), WikiData("Hadoop","then there is hadoop")))

val categoryMap = wikiData.map(x=>x.category).distinct.zipWithIndex.mapValues(x=>x.toDouble/1000).collectAsMap

val labeledData = wikiData.map(x=>LabeledData(x.category, x.text, categoryMap.get(x.category).getOrElse(0.0))).toDF

val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")
  .setPattern("/W+")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.01)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))

val model = pipeline.fit(labeledData)

model.transform(labeledData).show
```

### Naive Bayes

```scala
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(documentsAsWordSequenceAlready)

import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF

tf.cache()
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)

tf.cache()
val idf = new IDF(minDocFreq = 2).fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)

//to create tfidfLabeled (below) I ran a map set the labels...but again it seems to have to be 1.0 or 0.0?

NaiveBayes.train(tfidfLabeled)
  .predict(hashingTF.transform(tweet))
  .collect
```

Comment: I'm not sure I actually get where you are stuck Justin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ML `LogisticRegression` doesn't support multinomial classification yet, but it is supported by both MLLib `NaiveBayes` and `LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS`. In the first case it should work by default:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayes

val nbModel = new NaiveBayes()
  .setModelType("multinomial") // This is default value
  .run(train)
```

but for logistic regression you should provide a number of classes:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
  .setNumClasses(n) // Set number of classes
  .run(trainingData)
```

Regarding preprocessing steps it is a quite broad topic and it is hard to give you a meaningful advice without an access to your data so everything you find below is just a wild guess:

- as far I understand you use wiki data for training and tweets for testing. If that's true it is generally speaking a bad idea. You can expect that both sets use significantly different vocabulary, grammar and spelling
- simple regex tokenizer can perform pretty well on standardized text but from my experience it won't work well on informal text like tweets
- `HashingTF` can be a good way to obtain a baseline model but it is extremely simplified approach, especially if you don't apply any filtering steps. If you decide to use it you should at least increase number of features or use a default value (2^20)

**EDIT** (Preparing data for Naive Bayes with IDF)

- using ML Pipelines:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val tokenizer = ???

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")

val idf = new IDF()
  .setInputCol(hashingTF.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, idf))
val model = pipeline.fit(labeledData)

model
 .transform(labeledData)
 .select($"label", $"features")
 .map{case Row(label: Double, features: Vector) => LabeledPoint(label, features)}
```

- using MLlib transformers:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{IDF, IDFModel}

val labeledData = wikiData.map(x => 
  LabeledData(x.category, x.text, categoryMap.get(x.category).getOrElse(0.0)))

val p = "\\W+".r
val raw = labeledData.map{
    case LabeledData(_, text, label) => (label, p.split(text))}

val hashingTF: org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF = new HashingTF(1000)
val tf = raw.map{case (label, text) => (label, hashingTF.transform(text))}

val idf: org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDFModel = new IDF().fit(tf.map(_._2))
tf.map{
  case (label, rawFeatures) => LabeledPoint(label, idf.transform(rawFeatures))}
```

Note: Since transformers require JVM access MLlib version won't work in PySpark. If you prefer Python you have to [split data transform and zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203275/1560062).

**EDIT** (Preparing data for ML algorithms):

While following piece of code looks valid at first glance

```scala
val categoryMap = wikiData
  .map(x=>x.category)
  .distinct
  .zipWithIndex
  .mapValues(x=>x.toDouble/1000)
  .collectAsMap

val labeledData = wikiData.map(x=>LabeledData(
    x.category, x.text, categoryMap.get(x.category).getOrElse(0.0))).toDF
```

it won't generate valid labels for `ML` algorithms.

First of all `ML` expects labels to be in (0.0, 1.0, ..., n.0) where n is number of classes. If your example pipeline where one of the classes get label 0.001 you'll get an error like this:

> ERROR LogisticRegression: Classification labels should be in {0 to 0 Found 1 invalid labels.

The obvious solution is to avoid division when you generate mapping

```
.mapValues(x=>x.toDouble)
```

While it will work for `LogisticRegression` other `ML` algorithms will still fail. For example with `RandomForestClassifier` you'll get

> RandomForestClassifier was given input with invalid label column label, without the number of classes specified. See StringIndexer.

What it interesting ML version of `RandomForestClassifier`, unlike its `MLlib` counterpart, doesn't provide a method to set a number of classes. Turns out it expects special attributes to be set on a `DataFrame` column. The simplest approach is to use `StringIndexer` mentioned in the error message:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("label")

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(indexer, tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, lr))

val model = pipeline.fit(wikiData.toDF)
```

Comment: OK, here's my problem...and maybe I'm not thinking things through...and maybe I'm not thinking this through properly. But, if I go with NaiveBayes, then it expects LabeledPoint data. However, I cannot seem to figure out a way to get my documents through TFIDF and then know which vector is which so that I can label them with their category?

Comment: You can use either ML or MLlib. I've edited the answer.

Comment: HOORAY! This is definitely my weakest area of Spark and one I will be enhancing heavily in the coming year(s) :). However, for what I need right now this is awesome! I'll try to remember to add a bounty tomorrow to give you extra points for the effort.

Comment: @JustinPihony Oh, now I am disappointed... I actually wrote an answer to your latest question and realized it has been deleted on submission :D

Comment: Sure, I actually was headed down KMeans to solve it...hehe, just undeleted, so go ahead and Ill upvote (accept once I've successfully solved this stupid problem :p)

Comment: It is a good start point. Is relatively cheap and easy to apply. One thing you should keep in mind though is that it doesn't work well with very large number of dimensions.

Comment: Yah....I already ran into that(on a different attempt) when I tried to run it across all categories in wikipedia.....