# Spark __getnewargs__ error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to clean a Spark DataFrame by mapping it to RDD then back to DataFrame. Here's a toy example:

```
def replace_values(row,sub_rules):
    d = row.asDict()
    for col,old_val,new_val in sub_rules:
        if d[col] == old_val:
            d[col] = new_val      
    return Row(**d)
ex = sc.parallelize([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 2}])
ex = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ex)
(ex.map(lambda row: replace_values(row,[(col,1,3) for col in ex.columns]))
    .toDF(schema=ex.schema))
```

Running the code above results in a `Py4JError` with a very long stack trace ending in the following:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o801.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:333)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is going on here? How do I fix it? I am using PySpark 1.5.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is caused by the reference to `ex.columns` in the `.map(lambda...)` statement. You can't have references to an RDD inside the function being used in an RDD transformation. Spark is [supposed to issue more helpful errors in this case](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063), but apparently that didn't make it into this version.

Solution is to replace references with copies of the referenced variables:

```
def replace_values(row,sub_rules):
    d = row.asDict()
    for col,old_val,new_val in sub_rules:
        if d[col] == old_val:
            d[col] = new_val      
    return Row(**d)
ex = sc.parallelize([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 2}])
ex = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ex)
cols = copy.deepcopy(ex.columns)
(ex.map(lambda row: replace_values(row,[(col,1,3) for col in cols]))
    .toDF(schema=ex.schema))
```

Comment: You're right about the direct reason but it is a different issue than a JIRA you've linked. Ignoring pickling issue it is pretty much the same problem as I've described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31684842/1560062). Since DataFrame is just a wrapper around JVM object it cannot be accessed from PySpark action / transformation. But it would work just fine in Scala.