# __getnewargs__ error while using udf in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

There is a datafarame with 2 columns (db and tb): db stands for database and tb stands for tableName of that database.

```
   +--------------------+--------------------+
   |            database|           tableName|
   +--------------------+--------------------+
   |aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...|    tttttttttttttttt|
   |bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb...|    rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr|
   |aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...|  ssssssssssssssssss|
```

I have the following method in python:

```
 def _get_tb_db(db, tb):
      df = spark.sql("select * from {}.{}".format(db, tb))
      return df.dtypes
```

and this udf:

```
 test = udf(lambda db, tb: _get_tb_db(db, tb), StringType())
```

while running this:

```
 df = df.withColumn("dtype", test(col("db"), col("tb")))
```

there is following error:

```
 pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An 
 error occurred while calling o58.__getnewargs__. Trace:
 py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

I found some discussion on stackoverflow: [Spark __getnewargs__ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443475/spark-getnewargs-error)
but yet I am not sure how to resolve this issue?
Is the error because I am creating another dataframe inside the UDF?

Similar to the solution in the link i tried this:

```
       cols = copy.deepcopy(df.columns)
       df = df.withColumn("dtype", scanning(cols[0], cols[1]))
```

but still get error

Any solution?

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: I added more explanation to the question.

Comment: A UDF operates over every row, and returns one row each. I think it is because `df = spark.sql("select * from {}.{}".format(db, tb))` you're trying to query a DB per row using `udf`. You should try `map` over `rdd`.

Comment: Thanks, can you please put more codes. how should I get dtypes for each row (db.tb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you can not use *Spark dataframe* in the UDF. But since your dataframe containing names of databases and tables is most likely small, it's enough to just take a Python `for` loop, below are some methods which might help get your data:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

# assume dfs is the df containing database names and table names
dfs.printSchema()
root
 |-- database: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tableName: string (nullable = true)
```

### Method-1: use df.dtypes

Run the sql `select * from database.tableName limit 1` to generate df and return its dtypes, convert it into StringType().

```
data = []
DRow = Row('database', 'tableName', 'dtypes')
for row in dfs.collect():
  try:
    dtypes = spark.sql('select * from `{}`.`{}` limit 1'.format(row.database, row.tableName)).dtypes
    data.append(DRow(row.database, row.tableName, str(dtypes)))
  except Exception, e:
    print("ERROR from {}.{}: [{}]".format(row.database, row.tableName, e))
    pass

df_dtypes = spark.createDataFrame(data)
# DataFrame[database: string, tableName: string, dtypes: string]
```

**Note:**

- using `dtypes` instead of `str(dtypes)` will get the following schema where `_1`, and `_2` are `col_name` and `col_dtype` respectively:

  ```
  root
   |-- database: string (nullable = true)
   |-- tableName: string (nullable = true)
   |-- dtypes: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
  ```
- using this method, each table will have only one row. for the next two methods, each col_type of a table will have its own row.

### Method-2: use describe

you can also retrieve this information from running `spark.sql("describe tableName")` by which you get dataframe directly, then use a reduce function to union the results from all tables.

```
from functools import reduce

def get_df_dtypes(db, tb):
  try:
    return spark.sql('desc `{}`.`{}`'.format(db, tb)) \
                .selectExpr(
                      '"{}" as `database`'.format(db)
                    , '"{}" as `tableName`'.format(tb)
                    , 'col_name'
                    , 'data_type')
  except Exception, e:
    print("ERROR from {}.{}: [{}]".format(db, tb, e))
    pass

# an example table:
get_df_dtypes('default', 'tbl_df1').show()
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|database|tableName|col_name|           data_type|
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+
| default|  tbl_df1| array_b|array<struct<a:st...|
| default|  tbl_df1| array_d|       array<string>|
| default|  tbl_df1|struct_c|struct<a:double,b...|
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------+

# use reduce function to union all tables into one df
df_dtypes = reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1.union(d2), [ get_df_dtypes(row.database, row.tableName) for row in dfs.collect() ])
```

### Method-3: use spark.catalog.listColumns()

Use spark.catalog.listColumns() which creates a list of `collections.Column` objects, retrieve `name` and `dataType` and merge the data. the resulting dataframe is normalized with col_name and col_dtype on their own columns (same as using *Method-2*).

```
data = []
DRow = Row('database', 'tableName', 'col_name', 'col_dtype')
for row in dfs.select('database', 'tableName').collect():
  try:
    for col in spark.catalog.listColumns(row.tableName, row.database):
      data.append(DRow(row.database, row.tableName, col.name, col.dataType))
  except Exception, e:
    print("ERROR from {}.{}: [{}]".format(row.database, row.tableName, e))
    pass

df_dtypes = spark.createDataFrame(data)
# DataFrame[database: string, tableName: string, col_name: string, col_dtype: string]
```

**A Note:** different Spark distributions/versions might have different result from `describe tbl_name` and other commands when retrieving metadata, make sure the correct column names are used in the queries.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200792/discussion-on-answer-by-jxc-getnewargs-error-while-using-udf-in-pyspark).