# Using Word2Vec functions inside of a UDF in Apache Spark (v2.3.1)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, word2vec, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe which consists of two columns, one an Int and the other 
a String:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|user_id      |token                |
+-------------+---------------------+
|          419|                 Cake|
|          419|            Chocolate|
|          419|               Cheese|
|          419|                Cream|
|          419|                Bread|
|          419|                Sugar|
|          419|               Butter|
|          419|              Chicken|
|          419|               Baking|
|          419|             Grilling|
+-------------+---------------------+
```

I need to find the 250 closest tokens in the Word2Vec vocabulary, for each token in the "token" column. I attempted to use the `findSynonymsArray` method in a udf:

```
def getSyn( w2v : Word2VecModel ) = udf { (token : String) => w2v.findSynonymsArray(token, 10)}
```

However, this udf causes `NullPointerException` when used with `withColumn`. This exception occurs even if token is hard-coded, and regardless of whether code is run locally or in cluster mode. I used a try-catch inside the udf to catch the null pointer, and it is being raised on every row.

I have queried the dataframe for null values, there are none in either column.

I also tried extracting the words and vectors from the `Word2VecModel` with `getVectors`, running my udf on the words on this dataframe, and doing an inner join with my dataframe. The same exception is raised.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected outcome `Word2VecModel` is a distributed model, and its methods are implemented using `RDD` operations. Because of that, it cannot be used inside `udf`, `map` or any other executor-side code.

If you want to compute synonyms for the whole `DataFrame` you'll can try to do it manually.

- Load the model directly as `DataFrame` as shown for example in [using Word2VecModel.transform() does not work in map function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34448456/)
- Transform the input data.
- Join both using [approximate join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938672) or cross product and filter the result.

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be correct. We decided our particular Word2Vec problem was better addressed in Python, but still used Spark to extract training data.