# Logging in a UDF in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark

I am calling an API in my UDF and trying to log the output to a Logger and am getting serialization error.

Below is my Logger initialization code:

```
log4jLogger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

In my UDF, I am logging using

```
LOGGER.info("Message")
```

But I am getting the error

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o31.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

While registering the UDF

```
distance_udf = udf(distfunc, DoubleType())
```

Can you please correct me on what I should modify in my logging and also what if I want to log into a separate log file.

Thanks

Comment: This won't help you - [Calling Java/Scala function from a task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684842/8371915) - but explains why your code cannot work.